# How can I make the git-prompt.sh's output (branch etc.) bold?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, git

I use `git-prompt.sh` to customize `bash`'s prompt with Git information, e.g. branch.

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh

I want `git-prompt.sh`'s output to be bold, since other parts of my prompt is bold (see `PS1` below). I don't want to update `git-prompt.sh`, but instead make its output bold in `~/.bashrc`.

However, I can't make it work. If I boldify `$fmt`, then only the branch becomes bold, but not state information.

Any ideas?

`~/.bashrc`:

```
# ps1 {{{1

PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\] \$ '

if declare -F __git_ps1 &>/dev/null; then
    __git_ps1_venv() {
        local pre="$1"
        local post="$2"
        local fmt=" (%s)"

        if [ -n "${VIRTUAL_ENV}" ] && [ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT:-}" ]; then
            if [ "`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`" = "__" ] ; then
                # special case for Aspen magic directories
                # see http://www.zetadev.com/software/aspen/
                pre="[`basename \`dirname \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"\``] ${pre}"
            else
                pre="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`) ${pre}"
            fi
        fi

        __git_ps1 "${pre}" "${post}" "${fmt}"
    }

    GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
    GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE=1
    GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=1
    GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM="name"
    GIT_PS1_STATESEPARATOR=" "
    GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=1
    GIT_PS1_HIDE_IF_PWD_IGNORED=1

    PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1_venv "'"${PS1% \\\$ }"'" " \\\$ "'
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

From [`git-prompt.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/abf474a5dd901f28013c52155411a48fd4c09922/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L331)

```
# __git_ps1 requires 2 or 3 arguments when called from PROMPT_COMMAND (pc)
# in that case it _sets_ PS1. The arguments are parts of a PS1 string.
# when two arguments are given, the first is prepended and the second appended
# to the state string when assigned to PS1.
# The optional third parameter will be used as printf format string to further
# customize the output of the git-status string.
```

Appending `\e[1m` (SGR Bold Sequence) to `${pre}` before `__git_ps1` is executed should work in your case. In your case, you can do this
Since `${pre}` is initialized to the first argument of `__git_ps1_venv`, you can place `\e[1m` like so and use `\e[0m` to reset it.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1_venv "'"${PS1% \\\$ }\e[1m"'" "\e[0m \\\$ "'
```

Comment: Thank you. Don't I need to reset `\e[1m` in `${post}`?

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. After using your `PROMPT_COMMAND`, my prompt is as follows: `nlykkei@ubuntu linux-pwn (master *=) $`. However, the `*=` part is not bold.

Comment: @Shuzheng I've edited the question after testing it on my system, man, bash's quoting is weird. Can you test if the edit works on your system?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work (at least for me). I think the reason is that `git-prompt.sh` defines colors as, e.g., `local c_red='\[\e[0;31m\]'`, which effectively overrides your bold font escape sequence (`\e[1m`). Guess the only solution is to modify `git-prompt.sh`. However, I wonder how `zsh` themes manage to boldify Git information.